# How do you enable the secret-tool command (backed by gnome-keyring, libsecret and dbus) in a headless CentOS Docker container?

Tags: centos, docker, d-bus, gnome-keyring

I'm trying to use the `secret-tool` command to store a secret securely in a running headless CentoS 7.5.1804 Docker container, but can't seem to find which packages and/or configuration is necessary to make this work successfully.

Specifically, I want to be able to run this command:

```
printf "aPassword" | secret-tool store --label="test" foo bar
```

And be able to see that password by running:

```
secret-tool lookup foo bar
```

When I run the `secret-tool store` command, I get this:

```
printf 'aPassword' | secret-tool store --label="test" foo bar
** Message: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login
secret-tool: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login
```

I've followed the [ArchLinux Gnome/Keyring wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring) and attempted to do the same on a CentOS Docker container via the following steps:

```
docker run --privileged -it centos:centos7.5.1804 /bin/bash
# remainder of commands are in the container bash shell:
printf 'search localhost.localdomain\nnameserver 8.8.8.8\nameserver 8.8.4.4' > /etc/resolv.conf
yum -y update
yum -y install sudo gnome-keyring libsecret dbus-x11
yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
export DISPLAY=“:0.0”
eval "$(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)"
mkdir -p ~/.cache
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/keyrings
eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

From what I can tell, this *should* provide everything needed (gnome-keyring daemon, dbus session and secret-tool + libsecret) to allow the `secret-tool store` command to succeed, but if fails.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A year later, and I was able to revisit this.  After a full day of researching and trying various things, I was finally able to figure this out.  I hope this answer saves others the days of productivity I lost!

The missing link in the chain was that a keyring has to be created first before entries can be saved to it.  In this docker context, there is no user account, no login, etc - so no keyring that would have automatically been created by a desktop manager like Gnome.

As a result, you have to:

1. First create the keyring manually and then
2. Start the keyring daemon manually

When creating, the command requires a password from stdin to initialize the keyring. In this docker example, because it's just for testing and not actually used by a real user, I'm using a dummy password of a newline `\n` that is piped in to both the `--unlock` scenario (which creates a keyring the first time it's called) and the `--start` scenario which actually starts the daemon.

Here's the final working set of commands.  Note that the official base `centos` docker image isn't used - systemd services must be running for DBus, so we must use the official `centos/systemd` image instead:

```
docker run --privileged -d -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --name centos-systemd centos/systemd
docker exec -it centos-systemd /bin/bash

# remainder of commands are in the container bash shell:
yum -y install gnome-keyring libsecret dbus-x11

eval "$(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)"

mkdir -p ~/.cache
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/keyrings # where the automatic keyring is created

# 1. Create the keyring manually with a dummy password in stdin
eval "$(printf '\n' | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock)"

# 2. Start the daemon, using the password to unlock the just-created keyring:
eval "$(printf '\n' | /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start)"
```

Once this has been done, we can now store and lookup passwords:

```
[root@603a122f7555 /]# secret-tool lookup foo bar
[root@603a122f7555 /]# printf "aPassword" | secret-tool store --label="test" foo bar
[root@603a122f7555 /]# secret-tool lookup foo bar
aPassword
[root@603a122f7555 /]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my commands on a headless VM of Ubuntu:

```
apt install dbus-x11 gnome-keyring libsecret # ~79MB
export $(dbus-launch)
eval "$(echo '\n' | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock)"
echo xxx@gmail.com | secret-tool store --label="main" email address
echo $(secret-tool lookup email address)

kill -9  $(pgrep -f gnome-keyring-daemon)
# echo $(secret-tool lookup email address)  # no longer gives password
```

It looks like the keyring will need to be unlocked in any script to retrieve the secrets.

The trick was really using the eval command which I thought was just for Docker. This is the error without that, which has no solution on the net including a couple GitHub projects.

"secret-tool: Cannot create an item in a locked collection"

EDIT, this only worked once. Even after using `-r` to restart the daemon, killing the processes and rebooting. I cant get any new secrets even with different names, nor retrieve the stored one. 
 [Error "secret-tool: Cannot create an item in a locked collection"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/690295/error-secret-tool-cannot-create-an-item-in-a-locked-collection)