# Error "secret-tool: Cannot create an item in a locked collection"

Tags: gnome-keyring

I'm following the commands at, and created my own answer that only worked once:
[How do you enable the secret-tool command (backed by gnome-keyring, libsecret and dbus) in a headless CentOS Docker container?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473528/how-do-you-enable-the-secret-tool-command-backed-by-gnome-keyring-libsecret-an). It worked once (I verified output of the secret in my console scroll), but then receive the error "secret-tool: Cannot create an item in a locked collection" again. Any idea why?

Here are the commands:

```
apt install dbus-x11 gnome-keyring libsecret # ~79MB
export $(dbus-launch)
eval "$(echo '\n' | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock)"
echo xxx@gmail.com | secret-tool store --label="main" email address
echo $(secret-tool lookup email address)
```

Even after using -r to restart the daemon, killing the processes and rebooting. I cant get any new secrets even with different names, nor retrieve the stored one.